# C programming, char* length cannot cover the whole Array

Tags: c, arrays, measure

So, what the program does is, you write a day from your keyboard and he validates it. Your input can be lowercase or uppercase.
The problem is when i give it days over thursday. You can see that contor gets weird values. 
length_arr is the function i use to measure the length of the array.
 Any suggestions?

```c
int length_arr(char* x)
{

    int i, length;
    for (i = 0; x[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    }

    return length = i - 1;
}

void valid_weekday(char* day)
{
    bool incorrect = true;
    char *monday = "monday", *tuesday = "tuesday", *wednesday = "wednesday", *thursday = "thursday", *friday = "friday", *saturday = "saturday", *sunday = "sunday";

    while (incorrect) {
    int contor1 = 0, contor2 = 0, contor3 = 0, contor4 = 0, contor5 = 0, contor6 = 0, contor7 = 0;
    //printf("NOTE: Weekday can contain uppercase letters. Why? Because reasons.\n\n");
    printf("Enter a valid weekday, please!:\n");
    fgets(day, 20, stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i < length_arr(day); i++) {

        if (day[i] == monday[i] || (int)monday[i] == (int)day[i] + 32) {
            contor1++;
            //.. To understand where i stops.
            printf("%c\n", day[i]);
        }
        else if (day[i] == tuesday[i] || (int)tuesday[i] == (int)day[i] + 32)
            contor2++;
        else if (day[i] == wednesday[i] || (int)wednesday[i] == (int)day[i] + 32)
            contor3++;
        else if (day[i] == thursday[i] || (int)thursday[i] == (int)day[i] + 32)
            contor4++;
        else if (day[i] == friday[i] || (int)friday[i] == ((int)day[i] + 32)) {
            contor5++;
            // ... To understand where i stops. (i stops at 2)
            printf(" day %c\n", day[i]);
            printf(" friday %c\n", friday[i]);
        }
        else if (day[i] == saturday[i] || (int)saturday[i] == (int)day[i] + 32)
            contor6++;
        else if (day[i] == sunday[i] || (int)sunday[i] == (int)day[i] + 32)
            contor7++;
    }
    if (contor1 == length_arr(day) || contor2 == length_arr(day) || contor3 == length_arr(day) || contor4 == length_arr(day) || contor5 == length_arr(day) || contor6 == length_arr(day) || contor7 == length_arr(day)) {
        printf("Good, you entered good.\n");
        incorrect = false;
    }
    else
        printf("Wrong day format!\n");

    // Tests to understand why other contor get value too
    int a = (int)day[0] - 32;
    printf("%d\n", (int)day[3]);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", (int)friday[3]);
    printf("%d\n", contor1);
    printf("%d\n", contor2);
    printf("%d\n", contor3);
    printf("%d\n", contor4);
    printf("%d\n", contor5);
    printf("%d\n", contor6);
    printf("%d\n", contor7);
    if ((int)monday[0] == a)
        printf("one");
    else
        printf("two");
    }
}

void main()
{
    char* day;
    day = new char(20);
    valid_weekday(day);
    delete (day);
}
```

Comment: Your length_arr function is wrong, length of the string is just `i`; not `i - 1`. You can use [strlen](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) for determining the length of a string. Also, that is a strange way of doing string comparison. Look for  [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) or for case insensitive comparison [strcasecmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp).

Comment: is this c or c++ code? Also, why are you not using `strlen` ?

Comment: @t0mm13b: "*is this c or c++ code?*" Why do you ask? There's no C++ tag, and there's nothing C++-specific in the code.

Comment: `void  main()` should be `int main(void)`. Whoever told you to use `void main()` does not know C very well. Find a better source of information.

Comment: @KeithThompson look again, there's `new` and `delete`!

Comment: @t0mm13b: Good point, I missed that. sNow 11 : You need to decide which language you're using. If you're using C++, fix the tag (and be aware that `new char(20)` doesn't allocate 20 `char`s, it allocates a single `char` and initializes it to `20`; you probably meant `new char[20]`). And `void main()` is even more wrong in C++ than in C; it should be `int main()`. If you're using C, replace `new` and `delete` by `malloc()` and `free()`, and compile with a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type in `thursday` then the first `t` matches against the first `t` in `tuesday` and the rest of the array matches against the `hursday` in `thursday` - so you end up with `contor2` being `1` and `contor4` being `7`. In your conditional to see if the input was valid you check if any of the contor values is the full length of the string, which it won't be because thursday has 8 characters in it.